# Change youtrack issue id

Tags: youtrack

**Concise:**
Is there a way (with YouTrack-API or somehow) to change issue ID. Say from s-5 to s-30?

**Full story:**
We created YouTrack project to track scientific equipment, which we produce. One device - one issue. With custom fields, we created, it is VERY convenient way to handle "device stories".

The only problem we have, is that devices have their own id numbers. If we could change issue ID so, that it corresponds to device IDs, it would be very helpful. Especially helpful, when we reference a device from other issues and other projects, and to have links with real device ids, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. There's quite an old feature request on this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-11067.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Voted there too. But alias is a one solution. Changing number in id could be another solution in our situation. Anyway, looks like it is impossible and the alias issue looks almost abandoned.